# How do you remove a CanvasJS chart?

Tags: javascript, canvasjs

Is there a specific method used for removing a CanvasJS chart from the DOM? I can't find anything related to removing a chart in the official documentation.

Comment: you could just delete/empty the containing element.

Comment: @scrappedcola I have that part convered. Just thought maybe there was some `remove` or `destroy` method that I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

with my experience, The link which is a tag has a class of canvasjs-chart-credit, creat a custom CSS and set that class proper display to none and add importannt

```
.canvasjs-chart-credit
{
    display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: it worked. but CanvasJS Trial is still showing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [destroy method](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/methods/chart/destroy/) to remove CanvasJS Chart from the chart-container.